# Remove spaces in the string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file that contains numbers in this format :

```
84  152  100       
86  149   101     
83   149   99    
86  142   101
```

How can I remove the spaces and bring it in this shape :

```
84 152 100       
86 149 101     
83 149 99    
86 142 101
```

This is what I have tried so far :

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"data_1_2.txt");
string[] line = lines[0].Trim().Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

But the result of this input is :

```
84
152
100
```

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a bit of LINQ magic:

```
lines = lines.Select(l => String.Join(" ", l.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))).ToArray();
```

It will split each line using space as a separator, remove empty entries and join them back using space as a separator again.

Comment: @FarhanAfzalSaifee You're welcome! And just because you're new here, you should read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/208082) :) Welcome on StackOverflow!

Comment: Just a question for you @MarcinJuraszek, when I use such a thing.


`Console.WriteLine(line.Length);
Console.WriteLine(lines.Length);`

Its giving me same dimension, I tried to add a new coloum, but there is no affect.

Comment: I don't really understood what you're asking about right now.

Comment: Now after I have omitted all the spaces, I would like to know its dimension, how would I do that?

Comment: You've omitted the spaces, but it's still an array of strings, not a multidimensional array of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regular expression:

```
lines = lines.Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ")).ToArray();
```